# Script not working when passed to bash via -c

Tags: bash, quoting, process-substitution

Why does this work:

```bsh
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat <(date|awk '{print $1}')

$ ./test.sh
Thu
```

but not as a command passed to bash:

```
$ bash -c "cat <(date|awk '{print $1}')"
Thu  2 Apr 2020 12:52:10 BST
```

---

I'm running this on macOS

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your one-liner, the `$1` is within a double quoted string:

```
"cat <(date|awk '{print $1}')"
```

This means that it will be expanded by the interactive shell.  If the first positional parameter, `$1`, is empty, it will expand it to an empty string, resulting in an `awk` program that just prints its input:

```
awk '{print }'
```

Escape the `$` in `$1` as `\$1` to stop the shell from trying to expand it. Your complete command would then look like

```
bash -c "cat <(date|awk '{print \$1}')"
```

In your script variant, the `$1` is in a single quoted string.  The shell will therefore not try to expand it.

In this specific case though, it would be better to use just

```
date +%a
```

to print the abbreviated name of the day. See also the `strftime(3)` manual (`man 3 strftime`).

In newer `bash` versions (release 4.2+, i.e. not with the *default* `bash` on macOS, but with the one installed through e.g. [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)),

```
printf '%(%a)T\n' -1
```

would do the same thing without invoking any external commands.